# After upgrading to subclipse 1.8, eclipse 3.7.1 does not recognize the versioned files

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I uninstalled the subclipse 1.6.x version and then installed the subclipse 1.8.x, however, the files in the project are not recognized as being under version control (since the "Team" menu on files shows enabled the "Add to version control..." menu item.

I've installed too the TortoiseSVN 1.7.3 client and already "Upgraded" the whole local copy to the new format.

Any ideas how to make it work inside eclipse?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoint: does subclipse 1.8.x compatible with SVN 1.7, while subclipse 1.6.x was with SVN 1.6?

If yes, you **must to upgrade** you working copy to 1.7 format (WC-NG), maybe better to do it with CLI-client

Comment: Hmm, yeas I did upgrade the working copy (using TortoiseSVN). New data: After rebooting my computer, now Subclipse it does recognize the working copy under version control. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been working without Subclipse (e.g. using TortoiseSVN or some other client), and then install it, and are wondering why it doesn't recognize that your project is in SVN, you will have to go to `Team > Share Project`. Subclipse will then see that it's in SVN and then start working.

[image]